# How to get the current category name in an observer in magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, category

I want to get the name of current category name of a product after add to cart for this I'm using this  `$category = Mage::registry('current_category')` but it shows null on observer.

so which observer I should call to get this value after add to cart the product.

Please help me thank you.

Comment: What event are you observing?  `Mage::registry('current_category')` is only available on `catalog_category_view`

Comment: thank you.so how could i get this value when i add to cart product help i am new learner

Comment: Okay, a few questions. 1) What do you want to do with the category name? And 2) what happens if a product is in multiple categories?

Comment: yes it may be comes from multiple categories .i want to store the current category name in custom table from which current category its viewed and ordered.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**in config.xml** 
   
             
                
                    
                        singleton
                        Customization_Holdcategory_Model_Observer
                        categorypath

```
<checkout_cart_product_add_after>
    <observers>
        <holdcategoryi>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>Customization_Holdcategory_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>cartProductAddAfter</method>
        </holdcategoryi>
    </observers>
</checkout_cart_product_add_after>
<checkout_cart_product_update_after>
    <observers>
        <holdcategoryii>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>Customization_Holdcategory_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>cartProductUpdateAfter</method>
        </holdcategoryii>
    </observers>
</checkout_cart_product_update_after>
```

**in observer.php**

```
<?php
```

class Customization_Holdcategory_Model_Observer 
{
     protected $_myDropdownValue;

```
public function categorypath(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $categoryId = '';
    if ($category = Mage::registry('current_category')) {
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setcurrentid($category->getId());
        echo $category->getId();
    }
}
/* If you'd like to do the same while updating the shopping cart*/
public function cartProductUpdateAfter($observer)
{
    $this->cartProductAddAfter($observer);
}

public function cartProductAddAfter($observer)
{
    $currentcatid = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getcurrentidl();
    $_product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    $catIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();
    $catCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
                     ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                     ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $catIds)
                     ->addIsActiveFilter();

    foreach($catCollection as $cat){
        if($currentcatid == $cat->getId())
        echo "<br>".$cat->getId();
    }die;
}
```

}

?>

Comment: How to get exact category using ID in observer?

Answer (score 2):

You should use following way to get product's categories in observer.

Declare event observers in **config.xml**

```
<events>
    <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
        <observers>
            <custommodule>
                <class>custommodule/observer</class>
                <method>cartProductAddAfter</method>
            </custommodule>
        </observers>
    </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
    <checkout_cart_product_update_after>
        <observers>
            <custommodule>
                <class>custommodule/observer</class>
                <method>cartProductUpdateAfter</method>
            </custommodule>
        </observers>
    </checkout_cart_product_update_after>
</events>
```

Develop the Observers handlers

```
class Vendor_Custommodule_Model_Observer 
{
    /* If you'd like to do the same while updating the shopping cart*/
    public function cartProductUpdateAfter($observer)
    {
        $this->cartProductAddAfter($observer);
    }

    public function cartProductAddAfter($observer)
    {
        $product_id = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct()->getId();

        //Get the category ids
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
        $cats = $product->getCategoryIds();

        //One product can associate with more then one categories. 
        foreach ($cats as $category_id) {
            $_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($category_id);
            echo $_cat->getName();             
        }
    }
}
```

Another way

```
public function cartProductAddAfter($observer)
    {
        $_product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $catIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();
        $catCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
                         ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                         ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $catIds)
                         ->addIsActiveFilter();

        foreach($catCollection as $cat){
            print_r($cat->getData());
            //echo $cat->getName();
            //echo $cat->getUrl();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please do not use `load()` in a loop :)

Comment: can you tell me why should I not use `load()` and how to get category data without `load()` ?

Comment: As it is in multiple category so it get all the categories names.but i want just the current category name from which it add to cart.thank you.

Comment: how can you identify which one is current of your product have multiple categories assigned

Comment: Using load method inside a loop is bad for performance ... if you have the category IDs, you can use this instead: `$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->addIdFilter($categoryIds);` and loop over the collection.

Comment: @sv3n check my updated ans without `load()` ;)

Comment: that is the issue i have to get current category name among its multiple categories.as like if i use Mage::registry('current_category') in view.phtml it shows its current category name among all the categories .i want this after add to cart that from which current category its come.

Comment: ok so you can set your current category in cookie and then use that cookie in observer.

Comment: thank you for your helping your code is working very great .please tell me one thing if i add current category in cookie in this case what will happen if situation  arise like i open a product details page and its category name will set in cookie.then i back or from same page i order another product from side column featured product list than what will set in cookie ?i think it will remain previous  product category name for the new one which i ordered.

Comment: in case of different product category name will be replaced with new one.

Comment: @ShubhajayDas yes this logic will not work for featured products, because current category will work only for current product.

Comment: Please accept my and if you think its helpful to you. Thanks :)

Comment: @AasimGoriya How to get exact category using ID in observer?

Comment: @AasimGoriya Could you pls help me with my post -> https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/284557/57334

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `$category = Mage::registry('current_category')` while adding a product to cart.

You can do the following.

```
//Get the category ids
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
```

One product can associate with more then one categories.

```
foreach ($cats as $category_id) {
    $_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($category_id);
        echo $_cat->getName();             
    }
```

Comment: wherever you want category id

Comment: i just want current category name it shows all the categories wherever it is set that all name.thank you

Comment: this is the magento's default functionality. A product can have one or more categories. it is you which category you want to display.